# Blank space after file extension -> weird FileInfo behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems, fileinfo

Somehow a file has appeared in one of my directories, and it has space at the end of its extension - 
its name is "test.txt ". The weird thing is that `Directory.GetFiles()` returns me the path of this 
file, but I'm unable to retrieve file information with `FileInfo` class.

The error manifests here:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\somedir");
FileInfo fi = di.GetFileSystemInfos("test*")[0] as FileInfo; 
//correctly fi.FullName is "c:\somedir\test.txt "
//but fi.Exists==false (!)
```

Is FileInfo class broken? Can I somehow retrieve information about this file? I really don't know how did that file appear on my file system, and I am unable to recreate some more of them.

All of my attempts to create a new file with this type of extension have failed, but now my program is 
crashing when encoutering it. I can easily handle the exception when finding the file, but boy am I 
curious about this!

Comment: Have you run an OS disk checker to ensure that its not a corrupted file?
Would we be correct to assume that this is under Windows? If so which version?

Comment: Windows Vista Business x86, but I'm sure I have somehow created the file myself, about a year ago, according to the date

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Ending file names with a space is documented as a Bad Idea.**

From MSDN ["Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces (Windows)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> - Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not.

Also, the KB article ["INFO: Filenames Ending with Space or Period Not Supported"](https://web.archive.org/web/20100111005602/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115827):

> Problems can arise when a Macintosh client creates a file on a Windows NT server. The code to remove trailing spaces and periods is not carried out and the Macintosh user gets the correctly punctuated filename. The Win32 APIs `FindFirstFile()` and `FindNextFile()` return a filename that ends in a space or in a period; however, there is no way to create or open the file using the Win32 API.

`DirectoryInfo` probably uses `FindFirstFile()` and friends to produce directory listings. `File.Exists` is most likely implemented through `GetFileAttributes()` which probably suffers from the same problem as `CreateFile()` and will report a nonexistent file.

Hence, not a problem in .NET specifically, but in Windows itself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes i know of these files. I also got once such a beast thing. To get rid of it i don't know about a programming way in C#, but good old command line is your friend:

Open a console window in the given folder (or execute *cmd* and navigate to the folder with `cd` command). Now enter `dir /x` to retrieve the shortname of the files in this directory. Use this name to delete or rename the file by using the `del` or `ren` command.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver. That dir /x did the trick. I had the same problem and tried deleting the file using the full name + extension but was told the file couldn't be found. However I was finally able to delete it using the shortname.

Comment: You will be able to manipulate these files by bypassing the Win32 API, i.e. through the POSIX subsystem (`cygwin` commands such as `mv` and `touch` will gladly manipulate these filenames) or possibly by prepending the path with L"\\?\" (this will also likely to bypass the Win32 APIs idiosyncrasies.)

Comment: @vladr Thanks. Prepending path with "\\?\" for file ending with a space did the trick for WinAPI function `FindFirstFile()`. It might help also with other WinAPI functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate files with trailing spaces (among other edge cases) if you use the `\\?\` path syntax: `\\?\c:\somedir\test.txt` .